# Date Range In PHP?

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I have a DB created by a third party vendor that I'm now writing a new UI for.

The DB stores event start times as unix timestamps (in GMT). What I need to do is query this for a one day range. So presumably I simply need to do a:

```
SELECT * WHERE start > $last_night_at_midnight AND start < $tonight_at_midnight
```

The problem I'm running into is a simple way to combine the date/time functions in PHP to create those variables. It feels like everything I'm doing is way too complicated for such a simple procedure.

Does anyone have a simple solution to this?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really backwards way of doing it, but if you need to be able to do various date ranges, not just today or one day, you could combine the odd time/date features of both languages and go with:

```
$php_start = strtotime("Some valid date expression");
$php_end = strtotime("Some other valid date expression");

$result = my_sql_query("
          Select * FROM someDB 
          WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_column)) 
          BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME($php_start) AND FROM_UNIXTIME($php_end)");
```

using the DATE() in the query ensures that the sql won't bother looking at the time part of the data, and using FROM_UNIXTIME for all three means that the sql server is consistent in how it derives the dates.

My favorite way of getting a date range for just today is:

```
  $today_start = strtotime("today");
  $today_end = strtotime("+1 day", $today_start);
```

strtotime is actually better, I've found, then adding 86400 or anything like that, because strtotime handles DST better. Found that out last week.

Comment: If you are doing date/time manipulations or comparisons where the smallest unit is smaller than a day, DO NOT try to code it yourself: use libraries. They already have things like DST bugs sorted out.

Comment: Using the DATE() function has negated my need to do a 'between x and y' query, instead I just say if date() = date() and it strips off the time just the way I was hoping to.

Answer (score 6):

Check out PHP's [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) for plain-English to unix time conversion.

This lets you use "today midnight" and "tomorrow midnight" and other similar constructs, as Paolo Bergantino demonstrates.

Answer (score 5):

[strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime) - the awesomenest PHP time function ever.

```
$last_night_at_midnight = strtotime("today midnight");
$tonight_at_midnight = strtotime("tomorrow midnight");
```

Comment: midight will give you midnight *today*, which is in the past, rather than the future.

Comment: If I do a:
echo strtotime('10 mar 2009 midnight');
The result is 1236657600 which translates to 11pm. Any ideas why this may be happening? DST?

Answer (score 3):

[strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) is a useful one here...

```
$t1=strtotime("today");
$t2=strtotime("tomorrow");

$sql="select * from foo where timecol between $t1 and $t2";
```

At time of writing (09-03-2009 19:06), today equates to 09-03-2009 00:00:00 and tomorrow equates to 10-03-2009 00:00:00

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pick arbitrary days, use [gmmktime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php)

Answer (score 0):

The time() function in PHP might be of use here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

More specificaly, the example given on that page will probably tell you what you need to know. Take a look at the 3rd echo statement

Answer (score -1):

You could either create those Variables in PHP or in Mysql...

```
$tonight_at_midnight    = mktime(0,0,0);
$last_night_at_midnight = $tonight_at_mindnight - 86400;
```

The other possibility is in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE start > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND start < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
```

(not tested)